# Neutralizing sulfur-like smell from car

Tags: cleaning, smell, interior

A full bottle of jewelry cleaning (links product and material safety data sheet below) broke in my car and went unnoticed for a few days.  Now the car has a sulfur-like smell whenever I go into the car.  It dissipates within a few minutes, but then returns very quickly once I leave the car.

The primary chemical components are alcohol ethoxylates, and can decompose into carbon monoxide, carbon dioxide nitrogen Oxides, sulfur oxides and other toxic gases.

I have cleaned the area and had the carpet (rear driver) shampooed from a car detailer, but still the smell remains.

What chemical compound can I use to neutralize the smell permanently (enter equilibrium)?

- [Product Link (Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044B5WN6)
- [Product Link (Manufacturer)](http://connoisseurs.com/jewelry_care/liquid_dip_cleaners_silver_bath.php)
- [Material data safety sheet](http://connoisseurs.com/msds/MSDS-Silver-Jewelry-Cleaner.pdf)

Comment: Is it possible for you to just air it out for several hours with the doors wide open?

Comment: It probably isn't dissipating but instead you are getting used to the smell, a phenomenon called Olfactory Fatigue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_fatigue.

Answer (score 1):

Try rubbing a stainless steel item around the spill sight. Stainless steel has inert properties that take smells away. 
I use spoons..

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel_soap

Also note you may have to pull back the carpet as it was a spilt fluid. There may still be remains of it under the carpet on the floorboards..

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have a link you can jam up in there?